# insert in other tables after calling savechanges()

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I made a simple framework to Doing the CRUD using MVVM for my application as below (for the add method ):

```
public int Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        string entityName = GetEntityName<TEntity>();
        var fqen = GetEntityName<TEntity>();
        object originalItem;
        EntityKey key = ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey(fqen, entity);
        if (ObjectContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out originalItem)) return 0;
        ObjectContext.AddObject(entityName, entity);

         int  r = ObjectContext.SaveChanges();

        return r;
    }
```

//And the Context

```
private ObjectContext ObjectContext
    {


        get
        {
            return GlobalContext.MainObjectContext;
        }
    }
```

//and the Singltone

```
 public static S_Entities MainObjectContext
    {
        get
        {
            return Singleton.Instance();
        }
    }
```

in the ViewModel the Save() is implemented as below:

```
 public void SaveItem()
    {
        storeReceiptBusiness.Insert(CurrentItem);
        Items.Add(CurrentItem);}
```

the problem is when is call the Save() ,The CurrentItem will insert as expected but  the currentItem of the last added entity and the CurrentItem of the current ViewModel will added!
I need to Discard old changes and only add the Current value.
hope it was clear.
Thanks indeed.

Comment: I'd recommend not using a Singleton for EF.  It's better to create a context when you need it and dispose of it as soon as you can.  My team finds that the repository pattern works well for EF code.

Comment: I tested that but the error of "Multiple INstance..."  displayed...